# PHP Form/Mysql INSERT INTO not working

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Hey I'm Trying To add some data in my table through a form .
But the form is not working or somethings wrong with my PHP code .

This is the HTML

```
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="subform" id="subform" class="forms" role="form" >

        <label>    
        <input name="title" id="title" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="put the title here">
        </label>

        <label>    
        <input name="singer" id="singer" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Artist / Band">
        </label>

        <label>    
        <input name="songname" id="songname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Song Name">
        </label>

        <label>
        <input name="lyrics" id="lyrics" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Lyrics">
        </label>

        <label>    
        <input name="arrange" id="arrange" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Arrangement By ?">
        </label>

        <label>    
        <input name="channel" id="channel" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Channel">
        </label>

        <label>
        <input name="dllink" id="dllink" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Download Link">
        </label>

        <label>
        <select name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
        <option>Pop</option>
        <option>Rock</option>
        <option>Rap</option>
        <option>Classic</option>
        </select>
        </label>

        <label><input name="cover" id="cover" type="file" class="form-control"
        placeholder="Cover"></label>

        <div class="submit-btn">
        <input type="submit" class="Btn_submit" id="submit" name="button" />
        </div>

        </form>
```

And This is The PHP :

```
 if(isset($_POST['title'])){
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);

$category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);

$singer = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['singer']);

$songname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['songname']);

$arrange = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['arrange']);

$lyrics = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lyrics']);

$dllink = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dllink']);

$channel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['channel']);

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO songs (title, category, singer, sname, arrangement, lyrics, download, channel, reldate) VALUES('$title','$category','$singer','$songname',$arrange','$lyrics','$dllink','$channel',now())");

$sid = mysql_insert_id();
$newname = "$sid.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cover']['tmp_name'], "../covers/$newname");
header("location: upload.php");
}
```

Do You know What i'm doing wrong here ?
i've done this before with no problems .
but it seems like i'm forgetting something this time .

Comment: what error it's showing??

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error in your SQL query:

```
',$arrange'
```

There is a missing `'`.

You can check for SQL errors by running `echo mysql_error();` after the query.

Side note: The `mysql_*` functions you are using are becoming deprecated and will be removed from future PHP versions. Your code will stop working then. If you write new code, use `mysqli_*` functions or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have not passed the connection variable to mysql_query function.

If you are getting the connection by some other way then do the following and see:

Just print the whole post array and see anything missing.
Also print file array and see the presence of file and error.

Comment: The connection parameter is optional for `mysql_query()`.